# how to add files to github repository

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I want to add a bunch of files to a new git repository. I tried creating a new repository using github windows software, then I pasted all my files in the folder that was created and made a commit. It showed the message that 55 files have been committed but there is no change reflected in my github account. Am I doing something wrong here? What is the correct way of doing so?

Comment: Well, github works in two steps really.  You commit the files to the repository which is stored on your local machine.  Then you can "push" it to the github account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to push those commits to your GitHub repo.

This is the [synchronize repo feature](https://help.github.com/articles/synchronizing-repositories): it should create a repo for you on GitHub, and push your local commits.

That supposes you created your local repo with (see "[getting started](https://help.github.com/articles/getting-started-with-github-for-windows)"):

[image: https://github-images.s3.amazonaws.com/windows/overview/windows_new_repo.png]